# g++ math difference between ARM and INTEL platforms

Tags: math, gcc, g++

The following program gives 8191 on INTEL platforms. On ARM platforms, it gives 8192 (the correct answer).

```
// g++ -o test test.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double a = 8192.0 / (4 * 510);
    long x = (long) (a * (4 * 510));
    printf("%ld\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why? The problem goes away if I use any of the -O, -O2, or -O3 compile switches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume the "what every programmer should know about floating point" probably applies here.  Some of your problem is simply the C library used by the parser in your compiler at that time, some of it is the rounding and other factors.  my calculator even comes up with 8191.9999 so no doubt you are probably falling off the edge of the accuracy, another thing is since the compiler can see the entire problem here optimization simply results in your c programming being printf 8192 and no actual math code is produced.

Comment: the real answer is you should look at the disassembly and it will tell you the "why's" you are asking...

Comment: you are using floating point. so that's why.

Comment: print out the floating point result instead of truncating the precision.

Comment: I get 8192 on intel...

Comment: what arm platform, is this one with hardware float or soft? what version of each compiler, what version of each C library (both the one used by the compiler and the one used by the binary if they differ) gcclib, etc...

Comment: also why you would expect that to be a result of 8192...(see HuStmpHrr above)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it could be related to the [extended precision registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) on some architectures.

Answer (score 0):

```
long fun ( void )
{
    double a = 8192.0 / (4 * 510);
    long x = (long) (a * (4 * 510));
    return(x);
}
```

g++ -c -O2 fun.c -o fun.o
objdump -D fun.o

```
0000000000000000 <_Z3funv>:
   0:   b8 00 20 00 00          mov    $0x2000,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

No math, the compiler did all the math removing all of the dead code you had supplied.

gcc same deal.

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   b8 00 20 00 00          mov    $0x2000,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

arm gcc optimized

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a00a02    mov r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the raw binary for the double a is

```
0x40101010 0x10101010
```

and double(4*510) is

```
0x409FE000 0x00000000
```

those are computations done at compile time even unoptimized.

generic soft float arm

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4810    push    {r4, fp, lr}
   4:   e28db008    add fp, sp, #8
   8:   e24dd014    sub sp, sp, #20
   c:   e28f404c    add r4, pc, #76 ; 0x4c
  10:   e8940018    ldm r4, {r3, r4}
  14:   e50b3014    str r3, [fp, #-20]
  18:   e50b4010    str r4, [fp, #-16]
  1c:   e24b1014    sub r1, fp, #20
  20:   e8910003    ldm r1, {r0, r1}
  24:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
  28:   e59f3038    ldr r3, [pc, #56]   ; 68 <fun+0x68>
  2c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <__aeabi_dmul>
  30:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
  34:   e1a04001    mov r4, r1
  38:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  3c:   e1a01004    mov r1, r4
  40:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <__aeabi_d2iz>
  44:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
  48:   e50b3018    str r3, [fp, #-24]
  4c:   e51b3018    ldr r3, [fp, #-24]
  50:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  54:   e24bd008    sub sp, fp, #8
  58:   e8bd4810    pop {r4, fp, lr}
  5c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  60:   10101010    andsne  r1, r0, r0, lsl r0
  64:   40101010    andsmi  r1, r0, r0, lsl r0
  68:   409fe000    addsmi  lr, pc, r0
  6c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0,
```

intel

```
  0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 b8 10 10 10 10 10    movabs $0x4010101010101010,%rax
   b:   10 10 40 
   e:   48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
  12:   f2 0f 10 4d f0          movsd  -0x10(%rbp),%xmm1
  17:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 1f <fun+0x1f>
  1e:   00 
  1f:   f2 0f 59 c1             mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
  23:   f2 48 0f 2c c0          cvttsd2si %xmm0,%rax
  28:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  2c:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  30:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  31:   c3                      retq   


0000000000000000 <.rodata>:
   0:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   4:   00 e0                   add    %ah,%al
   6:   9f                      lahf   
   7:   40                      rex
```

so you can see in the arm that it is taking the 4.whatever (a value) and the 4*510 converted to double value and passing those into aeabi_dmul (double multiply no doubt).  Then it converts that from double to integer (d2i) and there you go.

Intel same deal but with hard float instructions.

So if there is a difference (I would have to prep and fire up an arm to see at least one arm result, already have posted that my intel result for your program verbatim is 8192) would be in one of the two floating point operations (multiply or double to integer) and rounding choices may come into play.

this is oviously not a value that can be represented cleanly in base two (floating point).

0x40101010 0x10101010

start doing math with that and one of those ones may cause a rounding difference.

last and most important, just because the pentium bug was famous, and we were lead to believe they fixed it, floating point units still have bugs...But usually the programmer falls into a floating point accuracy trap before then which is likely what you are seeing here if you are actually seeing anything here...

Answer (score 0):

The reason your problem goes away if you use optimisation flags is because this result is known *a priori*, i.e. the compiler can just replace `x` in the `printf` statement with 8192 and save memory. In fact, I'm willing to bet money that it's the *compiler* that's responsible for the differences you observe.

This question is essentially '[how do computers store numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)', and that question is always is relevant to programming in C++ (or C). I recommend you look at the link before reading further.

Let's look at these two lines:

```
double a = 8192.0 / (4 * 510);
long x = (long) (a * (4 * 510));
```

For a start, note that you're multiplying two `int` constants together -- implicitly, `4 * 510` is the same as `(int)(4 * 150)`. However, C (and C++) has a happy rule that, when people write things like `a/3`, the calculation is done in floating-point arithmetic rather than with integer arithmetic. The calculation is done in double unless both operands are float, in which case the calculation is done in float, and integer if both operands are `int`s. I suspect that you might be running into precision issues for your ARM target. Let's make sure.

For the sake of my own curiosity, I've compiled your program to assembly, by calling `gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad test.c > test.s`. On two different versions of GCC, both of them on Unix-like OSes, this snippet always ejects 8192 rather than 8191.

This particular combination of flags includes the corresponding line of C as an assembly comment, which makes it *much* easier to read what's happening. Here's the interesting bits, written in [AT&T Syntax,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax) i.e. commands have the form `command source, destination`.

```
 30    5:testSpeed.c   ****     double a = 8192.0 / (4 * 510);
 31   23                    .loc 1 5 0
 32   24 000f 48B81010      movabsq $4616207279229767696, %rax
 33   24      10101010
 34   24      1040
 35   25 0019 488945F0      movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
```

Yikes! Let's break this down a bit. Lines `30` to `36` deal with the assignment of the quad-byte value `4616207279229767696` to the register `rax`, a processor register that holds values. The next line -- `movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)` -- moves that data into a location in memory pointed to by `rbp`.

So, in other words, the compiler has assigned a to memory and forgotten about it.

The next set of lines are a bit more complicated.

```
 36    6:testSpeed.c   ****     long x = (long) (a * (4 * 510));
 37   26                    .loc 1 6 0
 38   27 001d F20F104D      movsd   -16(%rbp), %xmm1
 39   27      F0
 40   28 0022 F20F1005      movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
 41   28      00000000
 42   29 002a F20F59C1      mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
 43   30 002e F2480F2C      cvttsd2siq  %xmm0, %rax
 44   30      C0
 45   31 0033 488945F8      movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
 ...
 72   49                .LC1:
 73   50 0008 00000000      .long   0
 74   51 000c 00E09F40      .long   1084219392
 75   52                    .text
 76   53                .Letext0:
```

Here, we start off by moving the contents of the register pointed to above -- i.e. a -- to a register (`xmm1`). We then take the data pointed to in the snipped I've shown below, .LC1, and jam it into another register (`xmm0`). Much to my surprise, we then do a [scalar floating-point double precision multiply](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc211.htm) (`mulsd`). We then truncate the result (which is what your cast to `long` actually does by calling `cvttsd2siq`, and put the result somewhere (`movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)`).

```
 46    7:testSpeed.c   ****     printf("%ld\n", x);
 47   32                    .loc 1 7 0
 48   33 0037 488B45F8      movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
 49   34 003b 4889C6        movq    %rax, %rsi
 50   35 003e BF000000      movl    $.LC2, %edi
 51   35      00
 52   36 0043 B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
 53   36      00
 54   37 0048 E8000000      call    printf
 55   37      00
 56    8:testSpeed.c   ****     return 0;
```

The remainder of this code then just calls `printf`.

Now, let's do the same thing again, but with `-O3`, i.e. telling the compiler to be rather aggressively optimising. Here's a few choice snippets from the resulting assembly:

```
139   22                    .loc 2 104 0
140   23 0004 BA002000      movl    $8192, %edx
...
154    5:testSpeed.c   ****     double a = 8192.0 / (4 * 510);
155    6:testSpeed.c   ****     long x = (long) (a * (4 * 510));
156    7:testSpeed.c   ****     printf("%ld\n", x);
157    8:testSpeed.c   ****     return 0;
158    9:testSpeed.c   **** }
...
```

In this instance, we see **that the compiler hasn't even bothered to produce instructions from your code**, and instead just inlines the right answer.

For the sake of argument, I did the same thing with `long x=8192; printf("%ld\n",x);`. The assembly is identical.

Something similar will happen for your ARM target, but the floating-point multiplies are different because it's a different processor (everything above only holds true for x86_64). **Remember**, if you see something you don't expect with C (or C++) programming, you need to stop and think about it. Fractions like 0.3 cannot be represented finitely in memory!